# Add new key to list of dictionaries with the values from a different dictionaries if matched with value of one key in each dictionary in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

Create a new key value pair in a list of dictionaries if certain value of that list of dictionaries are as keys in dict1.

```
 dict1 = {4380: [{'name': 'john', 'age': 26}], 3450: [{'name': 'sam', 'age': 57}], 7150: [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 36}]}
```

The below list of dicts

```
listofdict = [{'department': 3490, 'floor': 1}, {'department': 4380, 'floor': 5}, {'department': 7150, 'floor': 7}, {'department': 7160, 'floor': 8}]
```

I did the following to assign to

```
for element in listofdict :
    if element['department'] in dict1.keys():
        element['Attributes'] = dict1[element['department']]
```

This is the output I got

```
output = [{'department': 3490, 'floor': 1}, {'department': 4380, 'floor': 5, 'Attributes':[{'name': 'john', 'age': 26}]},
          {'department': 7150, 'floor': 7,'Attributes':[{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 36}]},{'department': 7160, 'floor': 8}]
```

But I want to delete the dictionaries which are not in the dict1 from the final output.

expected output:

```
 output = [{'department': 4380, 'floor': 5, 'Attributes':[{'name': 'john', 'age': 26}]},{'department': 7150, 'floor': 7,'Attributes': [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 36}]}]
```

I want to avoid the dictionaries from the list which don't match with the value of one key in each dictionary from the list with keys in dict1

Comment: The first code snippet has at least one syntax error. Try to simply copy and paste the code (properly formatted) into the question from the source file.

Comment: The last snippet is also wrong. Try to put it in a Python shell, correct errors and copy it back. Adding a few newlines may also help readability.

Comment: Thanks, edited @m

Answer (score 0):

Copy the output to new list (omitting unwanted parts):

```
dict1 = {4380: [{'name': 'john', 'age': 26}], 3450: [{'name': 'sam', 'age': 57}], 7150: [{'name': 'Tom', 'age': 36}]}

listofdict = [{'department': 3490, 'floor': 1}, {'department': 4380, 'floor': 5}, {'department': 7150, 'floor': 7}, {'department': 7160, 'floor': 8}]


output = []

for element in listofdict :
    if element['department'] in dict1.keys():
        element['Attributes'] = dict1[element['department']][0]
        output.append(element)


print(output)
```

In your original question data structure in `dict1` and `listofdict` didn't match with your code so code was adjusted.

Hint: After executing this code, `listofdict` and `output` may share some dictionary objects (changing something in the dict affects content of both ) so `listofdict` shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: I have question, Is my code pythonic way to do? Or is there any simplest way like one liners to do?

Comment: @VamsiNimmala It may be possible to create a one-liner instead but it would be complicated (especially due to adding a key to the dictionary) and ugly, not really Pythonic.